# How to generate a WMS from ncWMS and put it in the OpenLayers?

Tags: wms, openlayers-2, netcdf

I am a beginner to make a web application.

I am using ncWMS to serve the netCDF data. And I put some data in the server, I got a interface like this:

[image]

This basically satisfies the function that I need. However, I am not happy with the GUI.

Can anyone please enlighten me on how to get a WMS from this server? As I would like to create a layer in the OpenLayers.

Answer (score 3):

For a basic WMS client, you should be able to just use standard WMS from OpenLayers. The important part is the GetCapabilities URL.

For WMS 1.1.1 is almost certainly something like:

```
http://{your server name}/ncWMS2/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1
```

Just change the version for WMS 1.3.0 (i.e. `...VERSION=1.3.0`).

Make sure that is working, by opening the URL in the browser.

So now when you create the WMS layer in OpenLayers, you use

```
url: 'http://{your server name}/ncWMS2/wms?SERVICE=WMS'
```

or a variation that meets your needs (e.g. to specify a WMS version; or to select a specific source, using the [ncWMS extensions](https://reading-escience-centre.gitbooks.io/ncwms-user-guide/content/04-usage.html#extensions).

Comment: Thank you! I created a WMS layer by: `url: 'http://localhost:1030/ncWMS-1.2/wms?SERVICE=wms'`. I did check the both **GetCapabilities URL** are working. Also I put it in the layers of the map. However, why nothing appears? Can you please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Its impossible to say without knowing what you did, what errors you've seen, and what debugging you've done (e.g. with firebug). Perhaps that would be another question?